# How do I use fromJSON with a matrix in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a GitHub Action where a script outputs a list of sites that need to be deployed and then that list is used a the basis for matrix that does the deploying. Here's an example illustrating my point:

```yaml
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.value }}
    steps:
      - id: matrix
        run: |
          echo '::set-output name=value::["site1", "site2", "site3"]'
  build:
    needs: [ setup ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        value: ${{fromJSON(needs.setup.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "${{ matrix.value }}"
```

However, the editor underlines `fromJSON` and complains *Invalid type found: array was expected but string was found*.

If I copy/paste the [fromJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) example from GitHub's documentation verbatim into my YAML file, I get a similar error and it doesn't work:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - id: set-matrix
        run: echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"include\":[{\"project\":\"foo\",\"config\":\"Debug\"},{\"project\":\"bar\",\"config\":\"Release\"}]}"
  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.matrix) }}
    steps:
      - run: build
```

Any clues as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you find a solution, i am facing the similar issue?